# [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring data jpa, trying to create a simple spring boot - data jpa- hibernate application. I am getting `2021-04-03 20:24:40.478  WARN 33252 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]`
in my console when I hit the url `http://localhost:8081/users` Below is my controller code,

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping(value="/users")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> result =  userService.getAllUsers();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Service class -

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> r = (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
        return r;
        
    }

}
```

Repository interface-

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>{

}
```

I have gone through various solutions available online but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with "Accept" header with which your browser is sending the request. Can you include your http request browser trace?